# SQL, создание объекта с динамическими свойствами разного типа

Tags: sql, ооп, postgresql

Задача: создать подобие класса объекта с динамическим количеством разных свойств.

1. таблица object - хранит единицы объектов
2. таблица template - хранит шаблоны объектов с разными свойствами
3. ? реализация хранения свойств каждого шаблона ? свойство может иметь разные типы данных

К примеру:
Toyota Camry (object) ссылается на шаблон -> "машина" (template) <- , в свою очередь на шаблон должны ссылаться свойства присущие только данному шаблону.

Используется база данных PostgreSQL и интерфес через скрипты Python.
Предполагаю это можно решить следующими способами:

1. Таблица "value" хранящая две колонки типа "text" (имя свойства и значение), записи которой ссылаются на ключ в таблицу template. При необходимости пользователь добавляет новое свойство типа "text", к примеру (дата производства -> datetime), а средствами языка программирования мы приводим text к нужному значению и сравниваем.
2. Таблица "value" со столбцами всех типов данных (int, text, date, cidr, ... ), пользователь добавляет новое свойство, а языком программирования мы контролируем, чтобы только единственная колонка содержала значение, а остальные были null, и средствами функции "COALESCE" выбираем строку которая будет содержать гарантированно одно значение одной колонки.
3. Таблицы "value_int", "value_text", "value_date", "..." ссылающиеся на таблицу template. Выборку осуществляем "JOIN" и средстави языка программирования контролируем "INSERT".

В процессе работы пользователь, при необходимости, может добавить новое свойство с указанием типа для шаблона объекта (например - инвентарный номер), и в карточке всех объектов появится новое свойство досупное для добавления/обновления/удаления значения.

Какой способ более оптимален для использования в работе? Существует ли более лучшее решение, чем выше приведенные, для реализации простейшего объектно ориентированного подхода для храннения данных?

Comment: Это называется [EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Comment: Похоже на то, но как лучше реализовать? MongoDB не предлагать! Кстати, в посте 10 летней давности 3 способ нахваливают https://habrahabr.ru/post/45935/

Comment: В постгресе с тех пор появилась поддержка безумств вроде jsonb, которые могут дать вам те черты Монги, которых вам не хватает. Поизучайте доки постгреса в этом направлении.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку про jsonb. Но это не для моего случая. В данном формате удобно хранить описание текстовых и числовых примитивных свойств. В моём случае, хотелось бы использовать более 3 фундаментальных типов (как минимум не хватает даты и сетевых адресов) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE , и к тому же, по свойствам объектов планируется шквал запросов с выборкой по условиям.

Comment: Очевидных проблем с подходом иметь E{AV×T} (по таблице на атрибуты и значения каждого типа) я не вижу. Полиморфных ссылок на уровне БД нет, это уже избавляет от многих проблем.